# Modelling acceleration of motorcycle using iPhone accelerometer

Tags: iphone, ios, signal-processing, physics, accelerometer

Attached is a piece of data with the iPhone in a pocket with the motorbike accelerating from 0 to 13 metres/sec (plot shown in green) and the raw accelerometer data (magnitude in g), the x-axis is in seconds. The speed is being sampled at 1 every second (using the GPS) and the accelerometer data is being sampled at 10 every second. Ideally if i were to accelerate at a constant rate (which is not the case on a motorbike or any vehicle) from 14s to 20s, i should have an acceleration of 13/6 = 2.16 m/s^2 = 0.22g above the stationary 1g (due to gravity). My assumption is that the forward acceleration will be much larger than the lateral movements (i.e. due to tilting of the bike, etc.), therefore allowing the magnitude of the x,y and z accelerometer components to be a good enough approximation of the forward acceleration of the bike. But as you can see, from 14s to 20s i get spikes in acceleration instead of a constant acceleration at 1.22g. This could be due to the bike not accelerating at a constant rate and the values that dip below 1g could be due to the jerk of the bike while accelerating. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: It is really hard to model the movement only from this data. Per-axis information is lost, and possibly there is spinning force, and shock from the ground involved. I recommend you redoing the experiment by fixing the iPhone location so that one axis (probably z is most intuitive) faces down, another faces forward, the other faces side (I know this can be only best-effort).  And look at the per-axis data. The second axis should be of the biggest interest, but there could be unexpected noise coming from other axes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Acceleration is a vector. I presume you're accelerating on a level track, so the accelerations will add like perpendicular vectors, so you should see an increase in magnitude of about 0.24 m/s = 0.024 g, which is barely visible on this scale (I think I see it, but I'm not sure).

   The wiggle in the acceleration curve continues when you're cruising at high (but almost constant) speed. So it's not caused by jerks in the drive, it's caused by the bumpiness of the ride and maybe some 4-5 Hz resonance in the suspension. (The bumps don't seem to get faster, so I doubt it's an unbalanced wheel.)

Comment: Yea but if i'm accelerating at a constant rate of lets say 0.22g, then shouldn't my accelerometer magnitude estimation be shifted up to 1.22g and wiggle there (wiggle due to bumpiness, etc.)? Because my assumption that the bike acceleration far exceeds any accelerations caused by bumpy roads, etc. is still valid, is it not?

Comment: @gambit14 No. Acceleration is a vector. It adds like a vector. If I go 10 miles North and 1 mile East, am I 11 miles from where I started? You have to either come to grips with vector addition or just take my word for it.